# How to mount existing Intel RAID ISM (RAID 0) device on Linux?

Tags: linux, raid, ntfs

I have two 1TB drives from 2011 that I need to get the data off of ASAP.

Both of these drives are working and were configured as RAID 0 under a Windows Vista machine. Both drives are plugged into my Fedora machine, and I need to mount them as a RAID device so I can pull data off.

The first drive is shown as /dev/sda and the second drive is /dev/sdb. The machine I was using configured some part of the RAID array in BIOS, where my current machine cannot perform such an operation.

Is there a way to mount these drives on my machine to access the data?

By running the command "sudo mdadm -E /dev/sda /dev/sdb" this is the output:

```
mdadm: /dev/sda is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: /dev/sda is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is not attached to Intel(R) RAID controller.
/dev/sda:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.0.00
    Orig Family : 004c6f77
         Family : 004c6f77
     Generation : 000002cd
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 6dcf9662:d3c699ac:3b3da1b4:011a761c
       Checksum : 0c68413e correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

[3Play]:
           UUID : 094c270d:4dd4aead:f6cc4ab7:e3a2fa3b
     RAID Level : 0
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : ?
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 3907039232 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 1953519880 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 7630936
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off

  Disk00 Serial : 9VP0XDQA
          State : active
             Id : 00040000
    Usable Size : 1953514766 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)

  Disk01 Serial : 9VPCVD99
          State : active
             Id : 00050000
    Usable Size : 1953514766 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.0.00
    Orig Family : 004c6f77
         Family : 004c6f77
     Generation : 000002cd
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 6dcf9662:d3c699ac:3b3da1b4:011a761c
       Checksum : 0c68413e correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1

[3Play]:
           UUID : 094c270d:4dd4aead:f6cc4ab7:e3a2fa3b
     RAID Level : 0
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : ?
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 3907039232 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 1953519880 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 7630936
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off

  Disk00 Serial : 9VP0XDQA
          State : active
             Id : 00040000
    Usable Size : 1953514766 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)

  Disk01 Serial : 9VPCVD99
          State : active
             Id : 00050000
    Usable Size : 1953514766 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
```

As you can see by the output, the drives are both alive, and the previous raid
configuration is recognized, however I cannot mount this.

After issuing the command "sudo IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1 mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb" I get this output:

```
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sda is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot -1.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot -1.
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md0 as -1
mdadm: added /dev/sda to /dev/md0 as -1
mdadm: Container /dev/md0 has been assembled with 2 drives
```

and finally after trying to mount it with "sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt", I get the following output:

```
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/md0.
```

after using the GUI tool gnome-disks, /dev/md0 shows up but says "Block device is empty"

I am probably going about mounting these incorrectly, and I need help.

Comment: If this data is important, engage a professional data recovery firm immediately. You have already done several things which put your data at risk and could possibly have destroyed it, such as not copying the drives and working with the copies.

Comment: Seconding @MichaelHampton. I wouldn't want to attach these without a proper RAID controller in between that could import foreign RAID configurations, and then only in read only to ensure I didn't scramble the data. RAID might save the data, but it can be pretty unforgiving.